# не работает SQL запрос к таблице

Tags: sql

имеется таблица данных
поля:

| product_id | attribute_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 15 | text1 |
| 102 | 16 | text2 |
| 103 | 15 | text3 |

нужно получить выборку, где заданы следующие условия `attribute_19 = 15` или `16`, а `text = text1`, или `text2`

```
SELECT * from table where (attribute_id = 15 and text = text1) and (attribute_id=16 and text = text2)
```

Запрос выдает пустой результат. MySQL -база. product_id.

Comment: вероятно, один из `and` («и») надо заменить на `or` («или»).

Comment: так у вас условие and а должно быть наверняка or

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, скорее даже 2 из 3

Comment: Спасибо, но нет. Замена на or увеличивает итоговую выборку, а результатом отбора должен стать элемент с заданными атрибутами и текстовыми значениями. После получения выборки массив можно конвертировать через array_unique. Я в ступоре каком-то

Comment: *Запрос выдает пустой результат.* Отож! ты требуешь, чтобы одно поле (attribute_id) было одновременно и 15, и 16 (и то же самое для `text`) - ну не бывает...

Comment: Да, так грубо не получится. Собственно, это для фильтра товаров по свойствам. Придется делать несколько выборок, затем искать совпадения в них перебором. Одним запросом не обойтись, увы.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо строгое соответствие атрибута и текста, то надо заменить условие на OR

```
SELECT * from table 
where (attribute_id = 15 and text = text1) OR (attribute_id=16 and text = text2)
```

Если же запрос должен возвращать данные, как это указано в описании(id 15 или 16 и text = text1 или text2)
То тогда запрос должен выглядеть так

```
SELECT * from table 
where (attribute_id in (15, 16)) and (text in ('text1', 'text2'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в выборку попадают элементы, удовлетворяющие одному условию, а нужно, чтобы только те, которые удовлетворяют обоим.

Comment: Вот на примере вашей таблицы, вы какие строки хотите увидеть в результате?

Comment: @AlexPavlov *в выборку попадают элементы, удовлетворяющие одному условию* Какое "второе" и на какой именно записи не выполняется?

Comment: оператор AND подобной таблицы логично дает пустую выборку. С этим разобрался. Теперь нужно придумать механизм получения совпадений из нескольких выборок.